# Call FragmentPagerAdapter from activity

Tags: android, image, android-activity, fragment

I want to create FragmentPagerAdapter adapter from activity. How I can do this?

I have used this way when I call from a fragment but now I want from an activity.

MyActivity.java

```
        // here error
            adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),
                    images.getImageItem());
            viewPage.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPage.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

FragmentPagerAdapter.java

```
public class FragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> itemData;

public FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
        ArrayList<String> itemData) {
    super(fm);
    this.itemData = itemData;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemData.size();
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    FragmentImageView f = FragmentImageView.newInstance();
    f.setImageList(itemData.get(position));
    return f;
}
}
```

Comment: @Kartheek The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, ArrayList<String>) is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(),images.getImageItem());
```

with

```
adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                images.getImageItem());
```

`getSupportFragmentManager` is method of `FragmentActivity`,not belongs to `Activity`,so your activity class must implement `FragmentActivity`.Notice that you should import package `com.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`,not `android.app.FragmentManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `getFragmentManager` call `getSupportFragmentManager`

```
 /**
     * Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated
     * with this activity.
     */
    public FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
        return mFragments.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
```

So your code will be

```
 adapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    images.getImageItem());
            viewPage.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPage.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Comment: Just call getFragmentManager,the first region is android source code.

Comment: @FireSun doesn't work because I am not in a Fragment

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar 
 
thank you for fast replay, from where I will get the variable mFragments?

Comment: @FireSun The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager, ArrayList<String>) is undefined